# Gnuplot histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have created a histogram for some data that I have in a .dat file using the

```
binwidth=...
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)

plot 'file' using (bin($1,binwidth) + binwidth/2):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
```

but because my file has over 1,000,000 entries that it reads from and puts into different bins, I don't know the exact frequency/density of each bin is. I would like to know the frequency or have it write the frequency to a file possibly, does anyone know if its possible? 
I was also wondering whether instead of frequency it was possible to plot percentage on the y-axis so example if my frequency is 50,000 and my total number is 1,000,000 then on the y-axis to have a percentage instead of the actual frequency?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `stats` command to get the number of entries.

```
stats 'file'
binwidth=...
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)

plot 'file' using (bin($1,binwidth) + binwidth/2):(1.0/STATS_records) smooth freq with boxes
```

To plot the percentage use

```
plot 'file' using (bin($1,binwidth) + binwidth/2):(100.0/STATS_records) smooth freq with boxes
```

Comment: You have saved me hours and hours of work! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I also figured out another solution by reading online (but its less convenient than what you mentioned) - for people with similar problems - 



    'filename'
     binwidth = ...
     bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)
     set table "hist.dat"
     plot fname1 using (bin($1,bw)+bw/2):(1.0) smooth frequency
     unset table

The 'set table' allows all the information about the histogram to be saved in a file, in this case "hist.dat"